# Closed question statment at the bottom of question is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have noticed since the change(E&R to ED) that closing questions does not have the right statement that reflects the changes form E&R to electronics design.

[Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12144/runtime-error-in-visual-simulation-environment-microsoft-robotics-studio)

> Questions on Electronics and Robotics are expected to generally relate to Electronics and Robotics, within the scope defined in the faq.

Is the closing statement supposed to reflect the changes?

Comment: I have also noticed that the Meta Page has also Electronics and Robotics Meta On the Page title (IE when opening up the page the title at the top of the browser is also incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I fixed the close reason on main, and the title on meta. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: it seems the mods are so used to the message it never processed in our brains. I missed this completely.

Answer (score 1):

It's also in the Meta FAQ (and possibly elsewhere):

> ### What is reputation?
>
> You must have at least 5 reputation on the main website to participate on **Electronics and Robotics Meta** - Stack Exchange.
> ...
> Amass enough reputation points on the main site and **Electronics and Robotics Meta** - Stack Exchange will allow you to do more things:
> ...
> At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That is very much intentional. We don’t run **Electronics and Robotics Meta** - Stack Exchange. The community does.

Comment: Fixed in [this change](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502/closed-question-statment-at-the-bottom-of-question-is-incorrect/504#504).